# NSTimer with weak self; why is dealloc not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, dealloc

Consider view controller with strong(or weak, the same) `NSTimer` property:

```
__weak __typeof(self) ws = self;
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:ws selector:@selector(timerTigger:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

But why does this view controller not invoke `dealloc` method, whether I pass `strong` or `weak` reference to `self`?

Here is the detailed code:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    __weak __typeof(self) ws = self;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:ws selector:@selector(timerTigger:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)timerTigger:(id)timer {
    NSLog(@"do someting");
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"SecondViewController dealloc");
}
```

Comment: Can you show bigger code context/try to reword your question? Right now its kinda hard to grasp the problem, at least for me.

Comment: Use Instruments and the Allocations tool to determine what is causing your reference cycle.

Comment: @Losiowaty I've edited this question for detail.

Comment: Have you tried to set `timer` explicitly to `nil` before releasing the controller.

Comment: @vadian I just want to know what's the thing leads viewController not be released.

Comment: @guitarflow can you answer this question?

Comment: From the docs: _The timer maintains a strong reference to target until it (the timer) is invalidated._ Did you try to `invalidate()` your timer?

Comment: @Alladinian I know `invalidate()`, but I am more curious ablout the reason above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSTimer` maintains strong reference to its `target` until the timer is invalidated. You don't get to choose whether `NSTimer` establishes a weak or strong reference. When you pass a weak reference, as long as `ws` is not `nil` by the time you start the timer (which it obviously won't be, in this case), `NSTimer` will establish a strong reference to whatever `target` pointed. Whether `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` establishes a strong or weak reference is not some inherent characteristic of the pointer that you passed to it, but rather a question of what that method does with that pointer it was provided.

To fix this strong reference behavior, you can adopt one of the following patterns:

- use the block based rendition of `NSTimer` and use "weak self" pattern inside the block;

  ```
  @interface ViewController ()

  @property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 repeats:true block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
          [weakSelf timerTigger];
      }];
  }

  - (void)timerTigger {
      NSLog(@"do something");
  }

  - (void)dealloc {
      [self.timer invalidate];
  }


  @end
  ```
- use GCD timer, which is also block based and therefore can also easily be configured to not keep strong reference; or

  ```
  @interface ViewController ()

  @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timer;

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

      self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
      dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
      dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
          [weakSelf timerTigger];
      });
      dispatch_resume(self.timer);
  }

  - (void)timerTigger {
      NSLog(@"do something");
  }

  @end
  ```
- use `NSTimer` with target/selector, but `invalidate` the timer somewhere logical (e.g. `viewDidDisappear` or the like).

  ```
  @interface ViewController ()

  @property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTigger:) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
  }

  - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

      [self.timer invalidate];
  }

  - (void)timerTigger:(NSTimer *)timer {
      NSLog(@"do something");
  }

  @end
  ```

Comment: Thankyou, but I'm still a little of trouble of how timer establish a strong refrence when I pass a weak target?

Comment: The strong/weak behavior is not a function of the pointer, itself, but rather what [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) does behind the scenes with that pointer. So, when you call `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, it takes whatever you pass as the `target` and establishes its own strong reference to it (e.g. ARC calls `retain` on whatever the pointer referenced). Whether the code that passed the pointer established its own strong/weak reference, or not, is immaterial.

Comment: @huangxinyu: weak/strong is a compile-time modifier on the type of a variable. When you pass something, a *value* gets passed. If you pass a variable, the variable is read for its current value, and that value is passed. The value is just an address; there is no weak/strong.

Comment: @Rob, it would be nice to mention that your first alternative are limited for iOS 10.0 or greater. That said, your post was really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) DemoViewController_19 *vc;
@end

@implementation Person
@end

@interface DemoViewController_19 ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) Person *person;
@end

@implementation DemoViewController_19

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    self.person = [Person new];
    __weak typeof(self) weaks = self;
    self.person.vc = weaks;
}

@end
```

After run you can see vc dealloc is not called. It depends on Person's property of strong attribute.